# Using Or in If statement

Tags: .net, vb.net, validation, if-statement

I am really new to vb.net coding. I searched and I didn't find something that answers it.

```
If Number.Text = "974.823" Or Number.Text = "231.65" Or Number.text = "567.32" Or Number.text = "476.45" Or Number.text = "149.39" Or Number.text = "675.19" Then
    win.text = "Success"
Else
    Stop
End If
```

I tried `OrElse`, but it didn't work either.

```
If Number.Text = "974.823" OrElse Number.Text = "231.65" OrElse Number.text = "567.32" OrElse Number.text = "476.45" OrElse Number.text = "149.39" OrElse Number.text = "675.19" Then 
    win.text = "Success" 
Else 
    Stop 
End If
```

Comment: Perhaps share the contents of your Number.Text?

Comment: what is your input and how exactly you want it to work?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: what is your problem actually?

Comment: Can you explain your "doesn't work" in detail?

Comment: Does your program actually stop? If not, then the code you have shown is not being run.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly the code you posted should work. The only reasons for it not to work is that the `Number.Text` doesn't equal one of the values in your condition (does it have spaces or some other characters in it?)

Secondly if you are using numeric values like this you should be comparing numeric data types not strings. You can use `TryParse` to make sure the value is in the correct type.

Thirdly using a `Case` statement can improve readability where you have multiple Or statements like that.

So I would suggest something like this:

```
    Dim d As Decimal

    'See if the value can be parsed into the appropriate numeric type. 
    'If not show an error
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(Number.Text, d) Then
        MsgBox("The value entered in invalid")
        Return
    End If

    'Use a Select Case statement comparing the Decimal with other values
    'The D after the number tells the compiler that this is a decimal value
    Select Case d
        Case 974.823D, 231.65D, 567.32D, 476.45D, 149.39D, 675.19D
            win.text = "Success"
        Case Else
            Stop
    End Select
```

Comment: Not up voting (but refraining from down voting) because direct equals comparison of double values can be fraught with difficulties. Better to subtract one value from the other and comparing it to and compare the result to an acceptable tolerance. e.g. _pseudo code)instead of `d == 12.34` have `Abs(d - 12.43) < 0.01`

Comment: @BinaryWorrier - fair point. I have modified the answer to use a decimal value which will not have the same issue.

Comment: What if we want a longer number, like an ip address...?

Comment: You can use a `Long` instead of `Decimal` to represent the IP value. Or even better you can use `IPAddress` objects and compare the `.Address` property (which is a `Long`)

Answer (score 0):

How about a different tact?

```
Dim successCodes() as string = {"974.823", "231.65", "567.32", "476.45", "149.39", "675.19"}
If successCodes.Contains(Number.Text) Then
   win.text = "Success"
Else
   Stop
End If
```

If you have your heart set on the ORs then try putting each in parenthisis

```
If (Number.Text = "974.823") Or (Number.Text = "231.65") Or (Number.text = "567.32") Then
   win.text = "Success"
Else
   Stop
End If
```

Its been a long time since I wrote VB so apologies for any glaring syntax errors

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what your problem is. but I would do a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) of string and check if its contain the String I wan. With that I can simply add in any other String that I wan in the later part with the [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx) method. eg: `acceptedNumber.Add("new value")`

```
Dim acceptedNumber As New List(Of String)(New String() {"974.823", "231.65", "567.32", "476.45", "149.39", "675.19"})
If acceptedNumber.Contains(Number.Text) Then
    win.text = "Success"
Else
    Stop
End If
```

Or

```
Dim acceptedNumber As New List(Of String)
acceptedNumber.Add("974.823")
acceptedNumber.Add("231.65")
acceptedNumber.Add("567.32")
acceptedNumber.Add("476.45")
acceptedNumber.Add("149.39")
acceptedNumber.Add("675.19")
If acceptedNumber.Contains(Number.Text) Then
    win.text = "Success"
Else
    Stop
End If
```